# Windows Server 2008 R2--how give a WCF service write permission to folder?

Tags: windows, iis, wcf, write

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2.

A WCF service running in IIS under ApplicationPoolIdentity needs permission to write to a folder.

This was fine when the WCF service was using the built-in Application Pool named "DefaultAppPool," which runs under the identity ApplicationPoolIdentity.  I simply gave the user "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" write permission to the folder.  The user "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" does not show up in the windows explorer security gui, but when the name is typed in and the "Check Names" button is clicked Windows recognizes the user and assigns the permissions correctly.

I had to change from DefaultAppPool to an application pool that I created, "MyAppPool."  MyAppPool is identical to DefaultAppPool in all particulars except the name.  It runs under the identity ApplicationPoolIdentity.  However, the Windows security gui will not allow me to give "IIS APPOOL\MyAppPool" permissions to the folder.  It tells me the object cannot be found.

Is there any way I can give "MyAppPool," which runs under ApplicationPoolIdentity, permission to write to a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep - it should work in an identical manner to DefaultAppPool.

Are you sure you're typing the name exactly as it appears in the IIS Manager GUI?

Location: Computer, name: IIS AppPool\YourAppPool should work in the GUI in R2.

Comment: Incidentally, if you stop the ApplicationHostHelper service, that might break name resolution for app pools. I doubt that's the case if DefaultAppPool works, though.

Comment: And! Has it been run before - have you seen the App Pool running in Task Manager with the name you're expecting?

Comment: Thank you, it does work.  I believe I forgot to select the computer as the location, and it was searching the domain for that user name.